# Group PowerShell jobs under parent process in Task Manager

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-10, taskmanager, start-job

I have a PowerShell script that runs indefinitely, installed on certain desktops as a Windows service. The script starts 25-30 PowerShell jobs every 15 minutes using the `Start-Job` commandlet, collects finished jobs and saves the data collected.

In Task Manager, these jobs appear as independent, ungrouped processes:
[image: Ungrouped powershell job processes in Task Manager]

Since June 2017 (build 16226, Windows 10) Task Manager groups processes by Application, like so:

[image: Example of grouped processes in Task Manager]

These 'Windows PowerShell' processes are being created by my application, so why are they not being grouped under it in Task Manager? Is there a way I can 'trick' the OS in grouping these processes under my application?

Comment: I'm having a hard time reproducing this. 1809 here, got about 50 "Start-Job -ScriptBlock { 1..100 | % { sleep 1; "Output $_" } }". If I run it in the ISE, they are grouped under the ISE. If I run it from cmd.exe, it's grouped under that.

Comment: Hi @Mark, thanks for taking a look. I'm also running 1809 (10.0.17763 Build 17763). I used Sapien's PowerShell studio to create the Service executable from the PoSh script. Perhaps this has caused some issue...

Comment: I would suggest you to try using Runspacepools, using `Start-Job` will eat up your resource and is not a good candidate for running in background in such cases. Hence you have only once process and 25 threads.